# I am getting mixed results when testing for specific numbers within a random method

Tags: java

When testing these two methods I am getting mixed results. Occasionally when testing, values that should be false are true and vise versa. I have tried returning a single number in the Roll method and that works just fine when testing.

```
 public class Game {

    public int Roll() {
        return ran.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }

    public boolean checkRoll() {
        boolean check;
        if(Roll() == 1 || Roll() == 5) {
            check = true;
        }
        else {
            check = false;
        }
        return check;           
    }

    public static void main(String [] args ) {  
        Game g = new Game();
        System.out.println(g.Roll());
        System.out.println(g.checkRoll());
    }
```

Comment: How are you testing that??? That method is returning random values... so sometimes May be true and some cases will be false....

Comment: `Roll` returns a random number (btw. a new one on each call), so you will get `true` in about 19% of the tries and `false` in the other 81%. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Incorrect java code i.e 
1. public Game 
2. { are not in correct open or close

Comment: I want to check if the values equal 1 or 5 based off the random roll and use that boolean for a later method. I was testing by having the value and its boolean value printed. So all numbers should be false except for 1 and 5 but when I run it for example it will print something else besides 5 or 1 as true. Is it an error with my testing?

Comment: You'll want to brush up on member (global variables).

Your problem lies in the Roll() method and checkRoll() is affected by that side effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
 System.out.println(g.Roll());
 System.out.println(g.checkRoll());
```

you actually run your roll function TWICE. (3 times if you count calling it inside IF/OR) So you print a different number than you test later in g.checkroll (as it rolls a new number by calling your Roll), so the "true" or "false" print is not related to earlier number. Either put your checkRoll function as a sub into your Roll-function, or use some global variable where you store the Roll before testing it, instead of rerolling it.

Comment: Actually `Roll` is called 3 times because `checkRoll`also does it twice.

Comment: Very True(tm). His IF/OR condition is running the function as well, so he generates two numbers and if EITHER of them are X, it returns true. Not sure if by design or design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Took comments into consideration and got it working thanks all

```
public int Roll() {
        return ran.nextInt(10) + 1;
    }

    public boolean checkRoll(int num) {

        int temp;
        temp = num;
        if(temp == 1 || temp == 5) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
public static void main(String [] args ) {


        Game g = new Game() ;

        int roll = g.Roll();
                System.out.println(roll);
                System.out.println(g.checkRoll(roll));
    }
```

Comment: Great Job! This could still use some improvements.
the Game object can hold the *currentRoll*. the roll() method could update *currentRoll*. and the checkRoll() can check the *currentRoll*.

Any variables defined on the object are available for use by the instance methods